# Trying to get property 'max_rating' of non-object in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have these three models in Laravel-5.8

GoalType

```
class GoalType extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'goal_types';

    protected $fillable = [
                  'id', 
                  'name',
              ];


    public function goals()
    {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Goal');
    }

    public function ratinglimit()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(App\Models\RatingLimit);
    }    
}
```

RatingLimit

```
class RatingLimit extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'rating_limits';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $fillable = [
                  'id',
                  'max_rating',
              ];

    public function goaltype()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\GoalType','goal_type_id','id');
    }    
}
```

Goal

```
class Goal extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'goals';

    protected $fillable = [
              'id',
              'goal_type_id',
              'goal_title',
          ];

    public function goaltype()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\GoalType','goal_type_id');
    }
}
```

Controller

```
$goals = Goal::where('is_approved', 3)->get();
```

A RatingLimit is associated with one GoalType (hasOne) and GoalType has many Goal

When I tried to render max_rating

index.blade

```
{{$goal->goaltype->ratinglimit->max_rating}}
```

I got this error:

```
Trying to get property 'max_rating' of non-object
```

When I changed it to:

```
{{ $goal->goaltype->ratinglimit ? $goal->goaltype->ratinglimit->max_rating : '-' }}
```

it deisplays '-', and the error is no more there. But max_rating in the database is not empty

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Is ratinglimit null? I guess your relation is not working, try to figure that out first by getting a goaltype and calling the `ratinglimit` function on that. Also you can just use `Ratinglimit::class` it's  a bit more dummy proof

Comment: `belongsTo()` allows for `null`; if `$goal->goaltype->ratinglimit` is returning `null`, then you can't access `->max_rating`. You've added the code to handle conditionals, which is good :) If it is **always** returning `null`, then you might have an issue with your relationship. Does your `goal_types` table have a `rating_limit_id`?

Comment: @TimLewis - No, goal_types table does not have have a rating_limit_id, but rating_limits table has goal_type_id

Comment: Then your relationship is a `hasOne()` :) `belongsTo()` requires the `model_id` to be on its table.

Answer (score 0):

`->get()` returns a collection! so you should loop it through foreach to have access to each item and then you can use your relation:

```
@foreach ($goals  as $g)
   {{$goal->goaltype->ratinglimit->max_rating}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: `hasOne` method doesn't return a collection